# dosbox86 error in compiling c source code

Tags: c, turbo-c

When I compile a c source code in dosbox86,error happens like this.

The code is listed as follows:

```
/* 
copy this file to dosbox86\tc, 
run dosbox86
File->DOS Shell
cd \tc
tc
Alt+C select Compile->Compile to OBJ 
Alt+C select Compile->Line EXE file 
Alt+R select Run->Run 
Alt+R select Run->User Screen 
*/

#include <dos.h>
#include <bios.h>
main()
{
   unsigned char a=0, hex[3];
   char far *p = (char far *)0xB8000000;
   int i, j, k;
   _AX = 0x0003;
   geninterrupt(0x10);    
   for(j=0; j<11; j++)     
   {
      p = (char far *)0xB8000000;
      p += j*7*2;          
      for(i=0; i<25; i++)  
      {
         *p = a;           
         *(p+1) = 0x0C;    
         sprintf(hex, "%02X", a);

         for(k=0; k<2; k++)
         {
            *(p+2+k*2) = hex[k];
            *(p+2+k*2+1) = 0x0A; 
         }
         a++;
         if(a==0)          
            goto done;
         p += 160;         
      }
   }
   done:
   bioskey(0);             
}
```

This is the screenshoot :
https://1drv.ms/i/s!ApD6Mds_Rgs6lzHq2liGB0QZRjlA

I do all things as the heading said but I failed.The dosbox86 tells me that

> Linker error, Undefined symbol '_main' in module COS

when I line exe file.

What should I do?

Comment: ...and what is _moudle COS_?

Comment: oh I am sorry I have corrected some mistakes.

Comment: Don't have live drive. Which version of C is it? If its just text in the output thats better copied to the question.

Comment: The file you show in your question has a `main` function, but at link time the linker complains that there is no `main` function. So the problem is not within your code, but you are probably using TurboC wrong (project settings or something similar)

Comment: This sounds a bit like there should be environment-specific startup-files, which prepare the runtime environment. `_main` is probably the entry point of code execution, which in turn should call your `main()` then. Maybe you got some compiler/linker flags wrong?

Comment: gcc 4.8.1,it sounds that it is the problem of dosbox86?In fact when I paste this code in Dev C++ and compile it in gcc4.8.1,many errors happens and it cannot run anyway.

Comment: The Professor requires us to finish a code with the  Compilation,also he shows us the c code above.It is ok when compiling to obj  but failed in linking exe file.

Comment: Oh,thanks all of u,I have emailed my professor and problem is solved now.